# Funcion Update Masivo sequelize - Node

Tags: javascript, sql-server, nodejs, sequelize.js

Buenas, estoy tratando de hacer un update masivo a una base de datos MSSQL desde Node utilizando sequelize. Todavía no entiendo muy bien todo ésto de las Promises, .then() etc.

Lo que estoy necesitando es que una función llamada por POST, que recibe un array de objetos JSON:

```
[{F1:'123',F2:'a',F3:'b',F4:'Z'},
{F1:'124',F2:'a',F3:'b',F4:'Z'},
{F1:'125',F2:'a',F3:'b',F4:'Z'},
{F1:'126',F2:'a',F3:'b',F4:'Z'},]
```

Dónde F1 es el id del objeto y F4 el campo a actualizar. Haga un update sobre todas las filas recibidas y envíe una respuesta.
Para un solo Objeto, hago sin problemas lo siguiente:

```
MODEL.update(
    {
        att4: art['F4'],
    },
    {
    where:{
            att1: {$eq: art['F1']}
          }
    }).then(function(result)
    {        
        res.status(200).send();

    }).catch(function(err)
    {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    })
```

Y está todo perfecto. Sin embargo, necesitaría que se realicen todos los updates de forma masiva, y luego, recibir una respuesta en el cliente, ya sea con la cantidad de filas afectadas, o el error que corresponda.

He intentado poniendo el MODEL.update([...]) dentro de una funcion que recibe un objeto JSON y con un Foreach iterar el array y hacer una llamada a ésta función por cada objeto, pero no he conseguido lo que necesito.

Espero puedan Ayudarme. Gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, he investigado y me encontré con `Promise.all`.

Pude hacer el update masivo, y de paso lo metí en una transacción para mantener la atomicidad de la consulta. Quedando algo así:

```
app.post("/method",function(req,res)
{   
    var objs = [];
    req.body.forEach(function(art) {
        objs.push(art);
    },this);

    myModel.sequelize.transaction(function(t){
        var Promises=[];
        for(var i = 0 ; i<objs.length;i++)
        {
            var newPromise=myModel.update({
                att4:objs[i]['F4']
            },            
            {
                transaction: t,
                where:{att1: {$eq: objs[i]['F1']}}
            });
            Promises.push(newPromise);
        };
        return Promise.all(Promises).then(function(result)
        {
            res.sendStatus(200);

        }).catch(function(err){

            res.sendStatus(500).send(err);
        });
    });
});
```

Espero le sirva a alguien mas.

**NOTA: Saber manejar Promises es muy importante**